# run pyspark date column thru datetime/pandas function

Tags: pandas, datetime, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe where one column is a date column.

I need to run this column thru a pandas/datetime function to calculate business hours.

However, I can't seem to get the conversion right:

```
df3 = df2.withColumn('test_date', add_one(df2.AssignedDate.toPandas()))
```

produces the error:

'Column' object is not callable

I'm trying to run `df2.AssignedDate` thru the following function:

```
def add_one(pd_date):

    if pd_date.isoweekday() == 6:
        pd_date = pd_date.replace(hour = 7 , minute=0)

    return pd_date
```

Comment: Have you tried a `pandas_udf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular pyspark.sql.functions to parse the timestamp and manipulate it directly:

```py
In [1]: from datetime import datetime
   ...: from pyspark.sql.functions import col, date_format, to_timestamp, when, dayofweek
   ...: 
   ...: frame = spark.createDataFrame(
   ...:     [(1, datetime(2019, 11, 4, 7, 15, 21)), 
   ...:      (2, datetime(2019, 11, 9, 6, 2, 4))],
   ...:     schema=("id", "time"))
   ...: 
   ...: replaced_as_string = frame.withColumn(
   ...:     "trunc", 
   ...:     when(
   ...:         dayofweek(col("time")) == 7, # different convention
   ...:         date_format(col("time"), "yyyy-MM-dd 07:00:ss")
   ...:     ).otherwise(
   ...:         date_format(col("time"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
   ...:     )
   ...: replaced_as_timestamp = replaced_as_string.withColumn(
   ...:     "trunc", 
   ...:     to_timestamp(col("trunc")))
   ...: replaced_as_timestamp.show()
   ...:     
+---+-------------------+-------------------+                                   
| id|               time|              trunc|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|2019-11-04 07:15:21|2019-11-04 07:15:21|
|  2|2019-11-09 06:02:04|2019-11-09 07:00:04|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
```

This has the advantage of staying entirely with Java objects for the internals, so you don't loose time transforming to and from Python objects.

Remark that the function `dayofweek` has a different count than Python’s `datetime.datetime.isoweekday()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Pandas UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf

@pandas_udf(returnType=TimestampType())
def add_one(pd_date):
    # If pd_date doesn't come as datetime object then uncomment the following line
    # pd_date = pd.to_datetime(pd_date)
    if pd_date.isoweekday() == 6:
        pd_date = pd_date.replace(hour = 7 , minute=0)
    return pd_date

df3 = df2.withColumn('test_date', add_one(df2.AssignedDate))
```

For more information see this Databricks [blog](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python-pandas.html)

Comment: I will try that.  Using the Zeppelin notebook, I wasn't able to load pandas_udf for some reason, so I was asking for a workaround.  It looks like pandas_udf is the only way to go

Comment: it seems that pandas_udf came with spark version 2.3, I am running on an earlier version - any other alternatives?